# "Has the say on it"

Tags: idioms, expressions

I know the idiom *have the final say*, but I wonder if we could use the same idiom without the word *final* in it? For example:

> He is the boss, he is the one *who has the say on it.*

Could the above sentence pass muster with native speakers? Trawling through some google pages revealed a number of results, where the above expression was used with somewhat the same meaning.

> Up to now, the government **has the say** on management issues and the general lines of the commercial strategy are negotiated in four year contractual plans.*--Corporate Reorganisation in the European Transport and Logistic Sector*

Comment: I think "has the say" does not make sense without "final" in the context you have proposed.

Comment: "Has the say" does not work - "has a say" does, but does not convey the same as "has the final say". Why would you want to remove the 'final' anyway? :)

Comment: [Have a say in](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/have-a-say-in)

Comment: @asymptotically- Does it mean that most authors on Google Books have used it incorrectly?

Comment: A [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+the+say%2Chave+a+say%2Chave+the+final+say%2Ccall+the+shots%2Ccall+the+tune%2Ctop+dog%2Cking+of+the+castle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) with some varieties for what you -imho- actually try to express

Comment: The corpus of contemporary American English lists seven examples for "have the say", but 83 for "have the final say". Plus one million hits on Google, I'd say it's possible to use, but it's not the favored way to express the idea.

Comment: @Noah Not incorrectly, just a different context. If they've written "has a say", it means that they're one of the responsible people, and not that they are the ones who make the final decision. You can see that [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+the+say%2Chas+the+final+say%2Chas+a+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). "Has the say" is barely used at all.

Comment: Sometimes, when the word *final* is removed, the sentiment is expressed as _the say-so_ – as in, "I'm Captain here by election, and it's me that has the [say-so](http://books.google.com/books?id=MWKcV6fkK0MC&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=%22I'm+Captain+here+by+election,+and+it's+me+that+has+the+say-so+or+no!%22&source=bl&ots=V6svngOi3j&sig=aqKEq4Mjr-nBdyIMrYyNtJp3_aA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y8oWUIv-OsL10gG304CYCg&sqi=2&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20Captain%20here%20by%20election%2C%20and%20it's%20me%20that%20has%20the%20say-so%20or%20no!%22&f=false) or no!" – often (but not always) hyphenated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Books initially claims [about 12,800 results for *"they have **the** say"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22court%20martials%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22they%20have%20the%20say%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=fYsWUJu3C-bE0QWXo4HoCw&start=20&sa=N&fp=1&biw=1306&bih=905&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b&sei=nYsWUMWwK4uY1AXKyYCIBA) - but if you follow that link and try to access the next page of results, GB admits there are actually only 31 (and less than a couple of dozen separate instances are relevant to OP's usage).

By contrast, [*"they have **a** say"*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they%20have%20a%20say&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) initially claims 75,000 hits, which I expect are mostly both relevant *and* "real" (in fact, after I paged through some results, GB revised its estimate to 203,000 hits).

GB's algorithm for estimating results almost certainly pushed up the value for the first search term because it shares everything except the apparently trivial *the/a* switch with the second search term.

For completeness, ["they have the **final** say"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22court%20martials%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22they%20have%20the%20final%20say%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=eI4WUPWFJuSh0QXBm4GQAw&start=80&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6a3022d01c5b6f1d&biw=1306&bih=905) tops out at 82 hits (initial guestimate: 42,000).

So even though there's no *grammatical* argument against *having **the** say*, idiomatically it's clear that's a "non-standard" version.

---

In terms of a difference in *meaning*, if someone has "***a** say*" in some decision-making process, it just means they're entitled to present their position in a discussion (they can *say* what they think). The implication of using the *indefinite* article is that *other* positions are also to be considered.

If someone has *"**the** [final] say"*, it means they are *the final authority*. Whether or not they contribute to the debate itself, they will ***say** what the final decision is* (as, for example, a judge). The implication of the *definite* article is that there's *only one participant* who has this authority.

---

I think the two different senses for this noun usage of *a/the **say*** are nicely matched by...

> "You will **have your say** later" *(first meaning; [chance to] **speak**)*
>
> "It will only happen **on your say** so" *(second meaning; declare/**command**, as final authority)*

Answer (score 6):

Please, this one isn't even close:

> **say**
>
> *noun* [ in sing. ]
> an opportunity for stating one's opinion or feelings: *the voters are entitled to have their say on the treaty.*
> • an opportunity to influence developments and policy: *the assessor will have a say in how the money is spent* | *the households concerned would still have some say in what happened.*

<sup>NOAD</sup>

Comment: I guess that's quite different to the connotation that should be expressed in OP's example.

Comment: @Em1 - yes, I agree with you. The OP is asking if the modified idiomatic phrase can be replaced without "final".

Comment: @Em1: How is this different from what is being asked? "[...] the voters are entitled to **have their say on the treaty.**"

Comment: @Gigili The voters take part, but they do not have any power to decide. The person who has the final say listens to the people who have their say on and may or not incorporate their opinion into his decision. However, the person or group who has the say (no final here) will not (necessarily) listen to anyone and only instructs how something has to be done. However, the border between "have the final say" and "have the say" are blurred, thus there are overlaps in which both are valid for expressing the same.

Comment: Said that, if a group (as in OP's example the government) "has the say" the people in this group could "have a say" in declaring rules and one of them may be the one how "has the final say" again.

Comment: In a nutshell: The OP's example do not ask for "stating one's opinion"

Comment: The OP asks: "I know the idiom have the final say, but I wonder if we could use the same idiom without the word final in it?" My answer confirms that this is possible.

Comment: @Robusto: your answer actually confirms that there is a similar idiom. But *have a say* and ? *have the say* do not mean the same.

Comment: Indeed, he asks if we just can leave out the word. And yes, you're answer state out that it is possible. But your answer is far away of being complete or fully correct, since you're missing the crux of the matter. **His examples does express something else then your quote refers to.** Thus, I'm sorry, but you're off the track.

Comment: @Em1: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you define a "fully correct" answer, if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: @Em1: Robusto gave the definition of the word "say" that is being used in those phrases from the OP's question. It is a noun and it works like any other noun. Thus you can have a say, you can have the say, you can have the final say, or you can have no say, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Well, both points in Robusto's answer refer to *have a say in/on*, but that does not fit in the OP's example since they are not referring to *state an opinion*.

Comment: @Em1 You are reading the definition posted too literally. The word "say" in this sense means an opinion or suggestion or influence. If you have _a_ say then you give your opinion. If you have _the_ say then your opinion is the only one given. If you have the _final_ say then your opinion takes precedence over the others. That's all.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Almost as I said one hour ago, but I insist on the significant distinction between **giving an opinion** and **being the decision-maker**.

Comment: FWIW, I find nothing objectionable in *have the only say*. But that is not the same as ? *have the say*, any more than *have the only vote* is *have the vote*.

Comment: @Em1: You might insist on many things that are irrelevant. This post answers the question and It's perfectly good as it is.

Comment: @Em1: the difference is a matter of degree. If you do not have the only say or the final say then your opinion is merely advice. If you have the only say or the final say then your opinion determines the decision. That is how the word is used.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 There's nothing new. However, we will not come to an end hence I opt out. There's everything said. Difference may be subtle or not, but also significant or not. You have another point of view, that's OK.

Comment: Note that the examples in the source you site do NOT say "he has THE say", they say "he has A say" or "he has SOME say", etc. The adjective here is crucial.

Comment: @Jay There is no adjective in those phrases.

Comment: I was referring to the adjectives "the", "a", and "some". (Articles are a subset of adjectives.)

Comment: @Jay No, articles aren’t really a subset of adjectives.  Not all noun modifiers are by definition adjectives.  Articles are subclass of determiner, however.  They have a particular slot in the NP.

Answer (score 3):

I see a significant difference between the saying *to have the final say on* and *to have the say on*. And it might be confusing if we also include the phrasing *to have a say in*. All three phrasing are somehow related and do have overlapping intersections, but their connotation is considerable different to each others.

I don't want to discuss their meanings here, however, the phrasing *to have the say* does indeed exists, even though rarely used.

This [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=have%20the%20say,have%20a%20say,have%20the%20final%20say&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000) shows that *have the say* is used fewest of all. [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) lists only seven examples for *have the say*, four of them in written news and two spoken. (I'm sorry but I don't know how to offer a direct link to that source.)

Thus, you can use this phrasing but maybe you should prefer one of the following idioms. A comparison on [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20the%20say,call%20the%20shots,call%20the%20tune,top%20dog,king%20of%20the%20castle,rule%20the%20roost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows again, that *have the say* is not commonly used.

- to [call the shots](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+the+shots) / to call the tune
- to be [top dog](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/top+dog)
- to be the [king of the castle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/king+of+the+castle)
- to [rule the roost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rule+the+roost)
- to be [in charge](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+charge)

Comment: If anyone's say is that the discussion of the difference between these three phrasings is important should raise their hands now or shut up completely. I've a quite good example expressing the differences between the sayings but I currently consider this as off-topic.

Comment: You probably should search for *have/had/has/having* + *the/a/any/some/no* + *say*. This is not special.

Comment: @tchrist I'm pretty sure the relative frequency is very similar, but if you have the time to compare 42 different possibilities, fine, do it. You might offer your results in an answer as well :)

Comment: And I picked [the most frequent version](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+the+say%2Chas+the+say%2Chaving+the+say%2C+had+the+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of a rarely used phrasing.  And *a*, *any*, *some* and *no* are not important to my answer since I'm answering on *have the say* not on *have a say* or anything else, which again is something completely different thing.

Comment: Your numbers are off. There are only 20 possibilities, not 42: *havethesay haveasay haveanysay havesomesay havenosay hadthesay hadasay hadanysay hadsomesay hadnosay hasthesay hasasay hasanysay hassomesay hasnosay havingthesay havingasay havinganysay havingsomesay havingnosay*

Comment: @tchrist You should have a Google search on "42 the answer to life the universe and everything". Of course the number does not match *rolleyes*

Answer (score 2):

To *have the final say* on a matter means, after all the debate has taken place, after all the alternatives have been analyzed, after all the pros and cons and risks have been evaluated, those with *the final say* (or *the last say*) in the matter get to make the decision on which course of action to take.

> After us kids all debated about where to go for the family vacation that summer, our parents finally told us we were heading to Niagra Falls.  After all, they had the final say in the matter.

To *have a say* in a matter means you are a stakeholder; someone may solicit your ideas, ask you to make a nomination, allow you to voice an opinion or raise a concern, and maybe even cast a vote.  But, in the end, you may disagree with the final decision, because you don't have *the final say* in the matter.

You can mention people who have *"a say in the matter"*, but that's **not** the same as *"the **final** say in the matter,"* not unless those persons (or governing bodies) are in a position to make the ultimate and binding decision.

So, when we change the article from *a* to *the*, how is that interpreted?  From the smattering of uses I found on [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20the%20say%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1988,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&safe=active#q=%22has%20the%20say%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&safe=active&sa=X&ei=V6YWUIbpKoXw0gHP5IGwCQ&ved=0CDEQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3alang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1960,cd_max:12/31/2000&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=66447dc2677bda7c&biw=1536&bih=789), I'd say that the sense of *final say* is implied:

> - *The general has the say over which troops will be sent*.
> - ...*the department still has the say so over who actually gets hired.*
> - *Taking the example of coffee, it is the farmer who has the say*.
> - *Wherever the flag of Sarawak flies, the government of Sarawak has the say. You are in the wrong and you don't have a leg to stand on.*

So, apparently, yes, you can use *"have the say"*, and yes, it essentially means the same thing as *"have the final say"* – but that's just my say in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard anyone say, "X has the say" meaning the same as "X has the final say", i.e. the ultimate decision-making authority. To the best of my knowledge, that is simply not the idiom.

We do say, "X has a say", meaning "has influence on the decision".

That is, the idiom calls for the article "a" when referring to someone who has influene, not "the". It calls for inclusion of the word "final" when referring to someone who has the ultimate authority.

Sometimes people use other words in place of an article in the "influence" case, like "some say" or "his say", etc.

It's the nature of idioms that they often have a very strict form. You can't replace words, even if those words are the appropriate part of speech. Think of almost any idiom and try to swap out words. Like, "something came up", meaning an unexpected event took place that interfered with previous plans. If I try to change that to, say, "something rose up" or "something came down", I've completely lost the meaning of the idiom.